# Number of reals such that $\frac{1}{x-f(1)}+\frac{2}{x-f(2)}+\frac{3}{x-f(3)}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $f(x)= x^3+3x^2+6x+2009$ and $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{x-f(1)}+\dfrac{2}{x-f(2)}+\dfrac{3}{x-f(3)}.$
>
> Then number of real solutions of $g(x)=0$ is

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Given $f(x) = x^3+3x^2+6x+2009\;,$ Now

$$f'(x) = 3x^2+6x+6 = 3[(x+1)^2+1]>0\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$

So $f(x)$ is an Strictly Increasing function.

So $f(1)<f(2)<f(3)\;,$ Now Let $f(1) = a$ and $f(2) = b$ and $f(3) = c\;,$

Then we get $a<b<c$

Now $$\displaystyle g(x) = \frac{1}{x-a}+\frac{2}{x-b}+\frac{3}{x-c}.$$

$$\displaystyle  = \frac{(x-b)\cdot (x-c)+2(x-c)\cdot (x-a)+3\cdot (x-a)\cdot (x-b)}{(x-a)\cdot (x-b)\cdot (x-c)}$$

Now How can i solve after that, help me

Thanks

Comment: If you set $g(x)=0$ you have a quadratic equation...

Comment: Thanks  David Quinn, But When we put $g(x) = 0,$ i get $(x-b)\cdot (x-c)+2(x-c)\cdot (x-a)+3(x-a)\cdot (x-b) = 0,$ After expanding I am getting $6x^2-(6a+4b++3c)x+(bc+2ca+3ab) = 0$

Comment: So calculate the discriminant (?)

Comment: So $\displaystyle D = (6a+4b+3c)^2-4\cdot 6 \cdot (bc+2ca+3ab) = ,$ But this is very Complex.

Comment: But you have the values of $a,b,c$.

Comment: Thanks  David Quinn , But $f(1),f(2),f(3)$ have large values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions. It is enough to see that
$$
g^\prime(x)=-\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{i}{(x-f(i))^2}<0.
$$

Comment: Thanks Paolo Leonetti , Means $g'(x)$ is an  Strictly  Decreasing function. So It cut $X-$ axis exactly at one point, Means $g(x) = 0$ has exactly one root.

Comment: No, pay attention: $f(-\infty)=0^-$, $f(a^-)=-\infty$, $f(a^+)=+\infty$, and so on..

Comment: Ohh Thanks Means $g(x) = 0$ has two distinct roots one roots

Comment: Ops, I was referring to $g$ indeed, not $f$..